# Eclipse does not recognize Apache library using Groovy plugin

Tags: eclipse, groovy, libraries

Look at the picture, I have already added libraries to Buildpath, but Eclipse does not recognize an Apache class. How can I make eclipse recognize new jars using Groovy plugin from codehaus?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typical eclipse failure.

`Project -> Clean` will fix it.

Comment: @iwxfer you tried this answer? If yes then were you able to get it working? If yes then select this as a relevant answer.

Comment: I tried Clean and worked but I also have to change import this way: import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*

Comment: You don't need `*` if you only import the classes you need. (This is also the recommended way.)